# Why Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

I need to fill in the binary matrix.

```
const matrix: number[][] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    if (!matrix[i]) matrix[i] = [];

    if (!matrix[i][j]) matrix[i][j] = []; //here is TS exception
    matrix[i][j] = 1;
  }
}
```

the line `matrix[i][j] = []` - throw a TS exception - `Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)***`.

What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: An empty array [] is a type of never[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused because you try to assign an empty array (`never[]`) to `number` as the error describes. Based off of your original matrix variable being a 2D array, this means that the 2nd check you have is useless and you can remove it.

```
const matrix: number[][] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    if (!matrix[i]) matrix[i] = [];

    // useless (and invalid) check!
    // if (!matrix[i][j]) matrix[i][j] = []; 

    matrix[i][j] = 1;
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQygJwJYA8BcMwFc4BGApsgNoC6FMAvDBQNwBQjAZiMjABQA2RsqNGAAZ6MAQB4YAdlGoA1HICUMAN6MYMNhx58YAK0Ej9MSTP0LlajRtQsuAQkQoMpVOWVO06V%20UEN11gEani5upHq%20tACMTBoAvoxxQA)

The reason why an empty array is the type `never[]` is because of it's *freshness*. If it was a variable, say:

```
const arr = []
//    ^? -- any[]
```

it would count as `any[]`. But since you're explicitly adding it to the array as an empty array, since it's fresh, it immideately uses what the type *really* is at assignment: `never[]`